Resize range in table
My question is what code to write to select the last 10 lines with data from the table (image)
.
So that, of course, each time a row is added, it selects a different range. I have been trying this code:
Dim tblBAZA As ListObject
Set tblBAZA = Sheets("BAZA").ListObjects("BAZA")
LR = tblBAZA.ListColumns(1).Range.Rows.Count
LC = tblBAZA.ListRows(1).Range.Columns.Count
tblBAZA.Resize(LR, LC).Select
Set Getrange = tblBAZA.Range(LR, 1)

And I have this error

I don't know the VBA well, so I have a problem with tables. I think the question is simple to solve but I don't know what just write.

Are you sure that what you're after is to resize the Table?  Resizing the Table means that you would be changing the range that the Table encompasses and it sounds like you're trying to select the last 10 rows, not change the range of the Table.  I would also ask what you're doing with the selected data after you select it.  If you're copying/pasting it to a different location, then there are much simpler ways of pulling out the last 10 rows.

I would like them to be displayed in the listbox. If you are willing to help me with this i will be greatfull;)

Reference Bottom Rows of an Excel Table

Main
Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Baza")
    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = ws.ListObjects("Baza")
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = RefTableBottomRows(lo, 10, True, True)
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Continue with the code, e.g.:
    Debug.Print rg.Address

End Sub

Help

Returns Nothing if the table was not referenced e.g. you forgot the Set... line.
Returns Nothing if a zero or a negative number is passed as the BottomRowsCount argument.
Returns Nothing if there are no rows in the table i.e. .ListRows.Count = 0 or .DataBodyRange Is Nothing.
If there are fewer data rows (lrCount) than the specified number (BottomRowsCount), only the former amount of data rows is (can maximally be) referenced.

Function RefTableBottomRows( _
    ByVal lo As ListObject, _
    Optional ByVal BottomRowsCount As Long = 1, _
    Optional ByVal ShowFailMessage As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal ShowSuccessMessage As Boolean = False) _
As Range
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Reference Bottom Rows of an Excel Table"
    
    ' Validate inputs.

    If lo Is Nothing Then ' no table
        If ShowFailMessage Then
            MsgBox "No table referenced!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If BottomRowsCount < 1 Then ' zero or negative 'BottomRowsCount' argument
        If ShowFailMessage Then
            MsgBox "The ""BottomRowsCount""" _
                & " parameter only takes a positive integer, which """ _
                & BottomRowsCount & """ is not!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Validate the number of data rows.
    
    Dim lrCount As Long: lrCount = lo.ListRows.Count
    
    If lrCount = 0 Then ' no data rows in table
        If ShowFailMessage Then
            MsgBox "No rows found in table """ & lo.Name & """ in sheet """ _
                & lo.Parent.Name & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Determine the number of data rows to be referenced and the row offset
    ' between the first data row and the first data row to be referenced.
    
    Dim RowsCount As Long, RowOffset As Long
    
    If lrCount < BottomRowsCount Then
        RowsCount = lrCount
        RowOffset = 0
    Else
        RowsCount = BottomRowsCount
        RowOffset = lrCount - BottomRowsCount
    End If
    
    ' Reference the bottom rows.
    
    Set RefTableBottomRows = lo.DataBodyRange _
        .Resize(RowsCount).Offset(RowOffset)

    If ShowSuccessMessage Then
        MsgBox "Referenced " & RowsCount & " row" _
            & IIf(RowsCount = 1, "", "s") & " (""" _
            & RefTableBottomRows.Address(0, 0) & """) of table """ _
            & lo.Name & """ in sheet """ _
            & lo.Parent.Name & """.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    End If
    
End Function


ok that was epic

It's the bad practice to display messages in functions. Return errors instead.

Thank you for help. The range display correct, but please check my answear. I cannot set this range and have the error that argument is not optional. Probably i have written something wrong. If you could help me with it i will be greatfull. @VBasic2008
